# Query with/without TRIM

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am using PDO to query my database. I am using an older version of Oracle which is 9i. The problem is when I query a data that does not have a primary key it returns 0 data when I did not include `TRIM` function and when I use `TRIM` function it also affects the performance of the system.

For example:

```
  $sql = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(USERNAME) AS TOTAL FROM ASUSERACCOUNT WHERE TRIM(USERNAME) = :username");
  $sql->bindParam(':username', $username);
```

As you can see above I added a `TRIM` because without that it returns 0 even if there is a data. My other problem is that I cannot change the datatype of the fields because it affects the batch process we are doing.

Here is the table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ASUSERACCOUNT(
      USERID NUMBER(20),
      USERNAME CHAR(20),
      PASSWORD CHAR(100),
      ACTIVE CHAR(100),
      PWEXPDT NUMBER(1),
      FAILEDLOGIN NUMBER(1),
      LSTFAILEDLOGIN DATE,
      RECORDLOG CHAR(100)
);
```

Is there a way to combat this?

Comment: What if you pad your parameter instead?

Comment: @Martheen what do you mean by pad my parameter?

Comment: Stop allowing your users to create usernames padded with whitespace.  And I'd also recommend checking such accounts, as it feels like a hack to me.

Comment: The answer is to fix your data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is the feature of oracle that if the datatype is char it automatically adds white spaces to fill the whole length

Comment: Oh...right, you should absolutely be using `VARCHAR` instead then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reference to this behaviour online, but you claim that `CHAR` columns need to be dealt with as though they're padded to full length with spaces.

I believe this is far more likely to be a problem with data storage.

Nevertheless, if you need to pad your values, you can use `sprintf` to do so.

```php
$username = sprintf("%-20s", $username);

$sql = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(USERNAME) AS TOTAL FROM ASUSERACCOUNT WHERE USERNAME = :username");
$sql->bindParam(':username', $username);
```

This will right pad your value with spaces, like so:

```php
$foo = sprintf('%-20s', 'foo');
$bar = sprintf('%20s', 'bar');
var_dump($foo);
var_dump($bar);
```

Result:

```
string(20) "foo                 "
string(20) "                 bar"
```